# Using Programmatic Images in Nivo SLider with asp.net and c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, slider, nivo-slider

"Only images or images wrapped in links are allowed in the slider div. Any other HTML will break the slider."

What would be the best way to programatically insert images from a database in c#?
I was using a label inside the div id="slider" tag but then realized the label would create the images within a span tag and therefore break the slider.

```
lblSlider.Text += "<img src=\"" + URL + "\" alt=\"" + address + "\" title=\"<a href='Featured/" + address" + address + ", " + city + "</a>\" />";
```

Comment: Also, I edited the code posted up there to take out my company's sensitive information and just now realized that in the process I messed up the anchor tag. Please ignore as it isn't important anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I haven't tried the other solution but I did this and it works:
Here are some global c# variables:

```
protected int count;
protected string[] arr = new string[20];
```

Then I assign values to the string array from my database in the Page_Load method.

And then I just write the nivo slider with javascript on my page:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.write("<div id='slider' class='nivoSlider'>");
        var count = <%= count %>; 
        var myArray = <% = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(arr) %>;
        for(var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            document.write(myArray[i]);
        }

        document.write("</div>");
    </script>
```

This solution seems easier to me, but if anyone thinks I should use the other solution over this one, let me know. Oh, and don't forget the namespace System.Web.Script.Serialization

Comment: WHere is the image being inserted from the DB.. wasn't that the original question?

Comment: Sorry for not being more specific, I was looking for the best way to write to the page without asp.net creating a tag. I didn't want to use javascript, but it seemed like the easiest route. I've now assigned the string array[] arr with "<img ... />" strings which pull the src from varchar imageURL in the database. Originally I had done similar, but assigned a label with the <img ... /> tags, which asp.net would then create a <span> tag and break the nivo slider.

Comment: I see I phrased it very poorly. I didn't mean storing images in a database, although that's great and I'm going to use your solution. I originally saved images onto the server and stored their URLs in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Use markup like this...

```
<img src='ImageHandler.ashx?ProductID=<%# Eval("ProductID")%>' 
    alt="<%# Eval("ProductName") %>" title="<%# Eval("ProductName") %>" />
```

... in conjunction with an image HttpHandler class like this (adapt for your own particular DB schema):

```
public class ImageHandler : IHttpHandler
{
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        if (context.Request.QueryString["productID"] != null)
        {
            try
            {
                string ProductID = context.Request.QueryString["ProductID"];
                if (Convert.ToInt32(ProductID) > 0)
                {
                    const string CONN 
                        = "Initial Catalog=xxx;Data Source=xxx;Integrated Security=SSPI;";

                    string selectQuery 
                        = "SELECT Photo FROM dbo.Products WHERE dbo.Products.ProductID=" 
                            + ProductID.ToString();
                    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(CONN);
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(selectQuery, conn);

                    conn.Open();
                    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                    dr.Read();
                    context.Response.BinaryWrite((Byte[])dr[0]);
                    dr.Close();
                    conn.Dispose();
                    // context.Response.End(); 
                    // caused an "Abort thread" error 
                    // - this is correct and is a special exception
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ErrorReporting.LogError(ex);   
            }
        }
        else
            throw new ArgumentException("No ProductID parameter specified");
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return true; // multiple images otherwise false
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have same requirement and tried the below code to accomplish the dynamic loading of images basing on category. These image loaded from my database. I am new to ASP.Net please let me know if I did anything wrong or did any blunders :).

in ASP.Net file:
I am using nivo slider append method

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function() {

        $('#slider').append('<img id="ad5" src=<%=__ad1ImageUrl %> />');
        $('#slider').append('<img id="ad6" src=<%=__ad2ImageUrl %> />');
        $('#slider').append('<img id="ad7" src=<%=__ad3ImageUrl %> />');
        $('#slider').append('<img id="ad8" src=<%=__ad4ImageUrl %> />');
        $('#slider').nivoSlider();
    });
</script>
```

My table looks like this:

```
    <table style="height: 183px; width: 100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
    <tr>
        <td align="left">
            <div id="wrapper">
                <div class="slider-wrapper theme-default">
                    <div class="ribbon">
                    </div>
                    <div id="slider" class="nivoSlider">
<!-- note that no images added here -->
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

In the code behind:
Use variable to store image url(s). You can now get the URL(s) from DB and get populated. In my code i have used these variables (can use array also) to capture url path. You can get the paths from any source like Database, Xml or ...

```
public string __ad1ImageUrl = "";
public string __ad2ImageUrl = "";
public string __ad3ImageUrl = "";
public string __ad4ImageUrl = "";

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        __ad1ImageUrl = "UserControls/Images/mainBanner1.jpg";
        __ad2ImageUrl = "UserControls/Images/mainBanner2.jpg";
        __ad3ImageUrl = "UserControls/Images/mainBanner3.jpg";
        __ad4ImageUrl = "UserControls/Images/mainBanner4.jpg";
    }
}
```